# Set minimum expandable height to List View cell Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, height, cell

As said in the title.

I want the minimum height of each cell to be 100dp but if the content inside of the cell increases beyond the height of 100dp I would like the cell to increase accordingly.

How is this done?

**EDIT** CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="100dp">        <---- Change this

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tn"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: What you have done till now please share your code here.

Comment: Probably with a custom `ViewGroup`. Android's stock containers do not do "or" well (100dp or `wrap_content`, whichever is larger). You could always use a 100dp transparent `View` somewhere as a shim to force a minimum height. Creating your own `ViewGroup`, perhaps by extending whatever you are presently and overriding `onMeasure()` and such, would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to this to calculate height dynamically

```
public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't realize it would require so much code.

Comment: This will not work for many lists. Once rows get recycled, the minimum height will go away.

Comment: This is code for dynamically measure size of adapter row . So you have to pass only list view it will automatically calculate its size and resize itself.